# Rails mysql Deleting duplicate tuples

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, duplicates

So i am working on this app, we have suppliers and each supplier has many scores and each score has details. there are two ways of entering scores for suppliers one way is via a form, the other is a excel upload. now we have some people who upload via spreadsheet that will update a single supplier and then upload the whole list which is creating duplicates for all her suppliers.

I wrote this sql statement. note: what makes a score unique is 1. its ID and 2. the combination of the valid_from and valid_until dates.

```
def remove_old_duplicates
  remove_dup = "DELETE s1 FROM `sms_development`.`scores` s1, `sms_development`.`scores` s2 WHERE s1.supplier_id = s2.supplier_id AND s1.valid_from = s2.valid_from AND s1.valid_until = s2.valid_until AND s1.id < s2.id;"

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute remove_dup
end
```

Basically what this is supposed to do is takes the table and combines it with itself then looks for all scores where the suppliers are the same and where the valid_from and valid_until attributes are the same. then it looks for the one with the biggest ID number and deletes the rest. only thing is its not deleting them. i run the query in work bench and it says its working fine just not in the app. i run this query just after new data is imported? any ideas on what could be causing this?

NOTE: the reason i am basing it off the ID number and not the created_at attribute is because rails gives me the created_at attribute if i create the score within the field, the excel upload uses a sql insert and thus dont get that attribute, since the id is unique i figured the bigger the ID the newer the record

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `DELETE s1 ...` is valid SQL?

Comment: Try this: `remove_dup = "DELETE s1 FROM \`sms_development\`.\`scores\` s1 JOIN \`sms_development\`.\`scores\` s2 ON s1.supplier_id = s2.supplier_id AND s1.valid_from = s2.valid_from AND s1.valid_until = s2.valid_until AND s1.id < s2.id;"`

Comment: @PinnyM Yes, it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't look valid to me - you can rewrite your query like this:

```
DELETE FROM `sms_development`.`scores`
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM `sms_development`.`scores`
  GROUP BY supplier_id, valid_from, valid_until
)
```

Comment: Using `IN` is slower when you have large data. So it is better to use `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
remove_dup = "DELETE s1 FROM `sms_development`.`scores` s1 JOIN
   `sms_development`.`scores` s2 ON s1.supplier_id = s2.supplier_id AND s1.valid_from = 
    s2.valid_from AND s1.valid_until = s2.valid_until AND s1.id < s2.id;"
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85340/2)**

Comment: thank you for your help! you are a rock star. also +1 for the demo i didnt know they had a SQL fiddle.